# SWI Prolog ODBC error

Tags: mysql, odbc, swi-prolog

I am attempting to connect to a local MySQL database using SWI Prolog (with ODBC driver) and I am receiving the following error

```
?- [family].
% family compiled 0.00 sec, 264 bytes
true.

?- open_db.
ERROR: ODBC: State S1090: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Invalid string or buffer length
```

The database name: prolog_test

The Prolog Code (family.pl)

```
open_db :-
    odbc_connect('mysql:dbname=prolog_test;host=localhost', _,
                 [ user('prologuser'),
                   password('prologpass'),
                   alias(localhost),
                   open(once)
                 ]).

children(X) :-
    odbc_query(localhost, 'SELECT (lemma) FROM tableName',X).
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: After implementing the function from @CapelliC (below), I was able to find out that ODBC was not set up correctly on my server. Following an [Ubuntu Post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ODBC) and [this post](http://www.1stbyte.com/2012/09/07/unixodbc-on-ubuntu-12-04-broken-and-unable-to-connect-error/) I was able to set up an ODBC connection on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ODBC) and [here](http://www.1stbyte.com/2012/09/07/unixodbc-on-ubuntu-12-04-broken-and-unable-to-connect-error/).

create the file: /etc/odbc.ini

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
odbcname     = MyODBC 3.51 Driver DSN

[prologtest]
Driver       = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Description  = MyODBC 3.51 Driver DSN
SERVER       = my.database.server.com
PORT         =
USER         = USER
Password     = XXXXXX
Database     = DBNAME
OPTION       = 3
SOCKET       =

[Default]
Driver       = /usr/local/lib/libmyodbc3.so
Description  = MyODBC 3.51 Driver DSN
SERVER       = localhost
PORT         =
USER         = root
Password     =
Database     = test
OPTION       = 3
SOCKET       =
```

On my machine, libmyodbc.so is located at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so

Changed the Prolog code to (much closer to the [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/odbc.html))

```
  1 open_wordnet :-
  2         odbc_connect('prologtest', _,
  3                      [ user('prologuser'),
  4                        password('prologpass'),
  5                        alias(prologa),
  6                        open(once)
  7                      ]).
```

Now I am able to make queries to the database

Answer (score 1):

I use the weaker alternative [odbc_driver_connect](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=odbc_driver_connect/3), it's working well:

```
myodbc_connect_db(Db, Uid, Pwd, Cn) :-
    format(atom(S), 'driver=mysql;db=~w;uid=~w;pwd=~w', [Db, Uid, Pwd]),
    odbc_driver_connect(S, Cn, [encoding(utf8)]).
```

Depending on application requirements, could be an advantage that no DSN is required.

Comment: Thanks for the help, implementing the function you described allowed me to find the error: "ERROR: ODBC: State IM002: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified" which lead me to the solution.

Comment: It's ok if you configure mysql driver in file /etc/odbcinst.ini. See http://www.kaffeetalk.de/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-with-unixodbc-under-ubuntu-14-04/ for example.